# Hit-testing text in Cocoa (Mac)?

Tags: cocoa, macos, graphics, core-graphics, text-rendering

Is there a way for hit-testing text? That is for example if I draw text "Hello graph!"" on the screen, within a bounding box, how can I tell the dimension and position of these blank rectangles (blank spaces):

- The blank rectangle above the letter "e"
- The blank rectangle that spans from above the letter "o" up to above the letter "p"
- The blank rectangle below the letter "H" up to the space before "g"

etc, you get the idea.

In other words how to find out which areas occupied by actual text and which areas that are really blank.

The platform (graphics library) is Cocoa on Mac OS X, the character set is Unicode (which probably rules out raw CoreGraphics API?), and the font can be anything that Cocoa can use.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Or looking from another point of view, getting a list of regions (rectangles) which minimally encloses the text.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the rect of a character in a `NSTextView` like this:

```
//Get the range of characters, which may be different than the range of glyphs
NSRange range = [[textView layoutManager]glyphRangeForCharacterRange:NSMakeRange(charIndex, 0) actualCharacterRange:NULL]

//Get the rect of the character
NSRect rect = [[textView layoutManager]boundingRectForGlyphRange:range inTextContainer:[textView textContainer]];
```

Then, get the `NSGlyph` that you want:

```
NSGlyph glyph = [[textView layoutManager]glyphAtIndex:range.location];
```

And draw it in an `NSBezierPath`:

```
NSBezierPath *path = [NSBezierPath bezierPath];
[path appendBezierPathWithGlyph:glyph inFont:myFavoriteFont];
```

Next, query the path for its bounds:

```
NSRect actualRect = [path bounds];
```

You can then compare those two rectangles.

Have a look at the [NSLayoutManager Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSLayoutManager_Class/Reference/Reference.html), the [Text System Overview](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/TextArchitecture/TextArchitecture.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000086i), and the [Text Layout Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/TextLayout/TextLayout.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000158i).

Comment: This constraints the solution to only in text views. Or in the degenerate case, create an invisible text view for every piece of text to hit-test on (which is probably won't be scalable when processing large amounts of text).

Comment: You could try taking out the first step and just try drawing the glyph in a `NSBezierPath`.

Answer (score 1):

You could draw the text over fully-transparent bitmap (via `CGBitmapContext`), then check that bitmap if a particular point is transparent or not.

If you need a list of rectangles (that is called *region* in 2d graphics), you'll have to implement that yourself or google for a library, as CoreGraphics and Cocoa don't have regions (at least documented).